# ARCH effect - Conflicting Results from Lagrange Multiplier Test and Ljung Box Test?

Tags: heteroscedasticity, garch, lagrange-multipliers

I want to test for presence of conditional heteroskedasticity in a vector of ARIMA(0,0,0) residuals.

For this purpose, I would like to see if both ARCH Lagrange Multiplier Test (on levels of residuals) and Ljung Box Test (on squared residuals) of R confirm the presence of ARCH effect in the said residuals. Note that I use lag 1 for both tests.

However, the tests return conflicting results. The former test returns a p-value of 0.123 which would mean that the residuals are serially uncorrelated. While the latter test returns a p-value of 0.023 which would instead mean that the squared residuals feature (a strong) autocorrelation.

Upon inspection of the plots of both ACF and the PACF of the squared residuals, it seems that there is some autocorrelation at lag 1. There is moreover some subject matter that would indeed justify the existence of such autocorrelation although I am not going to expand upon this point in this post.

[image]

[image]

Therefore, my questions are:

1) Is it theoretically possible that the two mentioned tests give conflicting outputs?

2) Are there some cases where one test gives a more "reliable" output over the other?

3) Would you suggest trying to fit GARCH models to my data and then compare them by AIC?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: On the squared residuals.

Comment: Yes, I used lag 1 for both tests.

Comment: What do you want to do with the model? If you want to forecast, compare the AIC of the model without GARCH and the model with GARCH. That will be methodologically sound. If you want to find the "true" model among the two ( ARIMA(0,0,0) vs. ARIMA(0,0,0)+GARCH(1,1) ) then use BIC.

Comment: Ok I'm gonna do right now. I want to compare GARCH based on AIC.

Comment: See the edit in the comment above. Other than that, I have to go. I will return tomorrow and will see if you had any more comments.